# make background transparent for progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView) for progress indicator while I do the background work via web service. I want to make the background transparent while the progressbar is showing. Is there any way to make the window transparent programmatically just like it does with progress dialog?

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private EditText email, pass;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private AVLoadingIndicatorView pb;
    private static final String LOGIN = "http://ubooktoday.com/android/login";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        pb = new AVLoadingIndicatorView(this);

        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListVActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    
    public void login(View view){

        if (!email.getText().toString().equals("") && !pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            loginRequest();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        

    }

    private void loginRequest() {

        startAnim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        stopAnim();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            String status = jObj.getString("status");

                            // Now check status value
                            if (status.equals("0")) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (status.equals("1")) {

                                session.setLogin(true);
                                db.addUser(jObj.getString("spa_name"), jObj.getString("user_id"));

                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListVActivity.class));
                                finish();



                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                params.put("pass", pass.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void startAnim(){
        findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        
    }

    public void stopAnim(){
        findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this . Make a custom dialog class

```
public class CShowProgress {
public static CShowProgress mCShowProgress;
public Dialog mDialog;

public CShowProgress() {
}

public static CShowProgress getInstance() {
    if (mCShowProgress== null) {
        mCShowProgress= new CShowProgress();
    }
    return mCShowProgress;
}

public void showProgress(Context mContext) {
    mDialog= new Dialog(mContext);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_layout);
    mDialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    mDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgress() {
    if (mDialog!= null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog= null;
    }
  }
}
```

Corresponding XML **custom_progress_layout.xml**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
     android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
     app:indicator="SemiCircleSpin"
     app:indicator_color="@android:color/black"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:visibility="visible" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And the Activity

```
  CShowProgress cShowProgress = CShowProgress.getInstance();
  cShowProgress.showProgress(Activity.this);
```

and hide by calling

```
  cShowProgress.hideProgress();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Happy coding broah :) :) @SomnathPal

Comment: @Sanoop please: I've tried many ways with this library but the animation does not begin, images are shown static. May this could have relation to my linearlayout? Thanks a lot and sorry bothering you.

Comment: The problem is: RelativeLayout would mess my layout... Didn't even try. Really thank you for your attention. God bless.

Comment: No worries,. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Login.this,R.style.MyProgressTheme);
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
pd.show();
```

And create **Theme** in values\styles.xml

```
<style name="MyProgressTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
   <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And also add this **Theme** in values\styles.xml

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle">
   <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And add values\colors.xml

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

**EDIT 1**

```
 <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/avloadingIndicatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  //or your custom size
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  //or your custom size
    android:visibility="visible"  //visible or gone
    app:indicator="BallPulse"
    app:indicator_color="your color"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

this might helps you.

Comment: I wanted to have the same progressbar library and not to use progress dialog. Is it possible? @Sathish